# macOS 14.1.1 Spotlight crashing

Tags: crash, spotlight

I have a MacBook Pro 13 inch(Intel, 2020, 4 Thunderbolt 3 ports) that is running macOS Sonoma 14.1.1(23B81) and when I press the spotlight icon and try to type **anything**, the text field disappears, and the spotlight icon from the menu bar disappears for a split second before coming back. Restarting the computer doesn't seem to work. This computer started doing this after I updated it. Even safe mode doesn't seem to fix the issue. Also, I have SIP turned off.

Turning on SIP does not fix the issue.

Comment: Is there a crash report

Comment: Does previous version work fine?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur The previous version worked fine. Only when I updated it then things went wrong

Comment: @Ruskes There is no crash report.

Comment: Note the exact time, then go to console>system log and check it out

Comment: @Ruskes When I went to the console and system.log and crashed spotlight, nothing happened.

Comment: So it does not register as system error, try disconnecting the thunderbolts, to evaluate a break in communication

Comment: @Ruskes What do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you have external drives connected that spotlight tries to read

Comment: @Ruskes No I have no external drives or other volumes or partitions.

Comment: Boot in safe mode and test.

Comment: @LincD. I already tried to boot into safe mode. Check the question.

Comment: Why did you disable SIP?

Comment: @LincD. I disabled SIP because I thought it would do something, however it did not.

Comment: Please open a Terminal window and paste the following command: log stream --predicate 'subsystem beginswith "com.apple.spotlight"'
Then press Return and try do a Spotlight search. In the Terminal window, press command-period to stop the command. Paste the output into a reply. Be sure to redact any personal information, such as your name.

Comment: @LincD. it said https://pastebin.com/2B1T6910

Comment: In Sytems Settings > General > Language & Region, please change the Region temporarily to another one, preferably with a language you can read, and test, then change it back and test again. If there is no change, post the output of this command: mdimport -L | grep -v /System

Comment: @LincD. I changed it to Costa Rica and it worked. However, it doesn't work when I change it back to Canada. It works for a few seconds but then it crashes again.

Comment: So you seem to be triggering a bug in the Canadian localization, in a keyboard layout, or maybe in a third-party importer. This could get complicated. Please post (a) a screenshot of the Region settings so I can reproduce them, and (b) the output of the command in my last comment. I don't have an Intel Mac so I may not be able to reproduce the bug. If anyone else is following and can chime in, please do so.

Comment: @LincD. I don't know how to post an image so here are the settings in text: English(Canada) - Primary, Chinese Simplified, Canada, gregorian, celsius, metric, Sunday, 2023-08-19, 1,234,567.89, and universal.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug with those settings. What about the command output?

Comment: @LincD. What command output?

Comment: mdimport -L | grep -v /System

Comment: @LincD. Paths: id(501) (
    "/Library/Spotlight/iBooksAuthor.mdimporter",
    "/Applications/Microsoft Outlook.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/Microsoft Outlook Spotlight Importer.mdimporter",
    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/uuid.mdimporter"
)

Comment: The Outlook importer might be the culprit. Do you have the latest version of Outlook? Does search work within Outlook? What about the Finder? Finally, I would try deleting Outlook temporarily to test, then reinstalling it.

Comment: @LincD. I deleted outlook but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please enable the Guest User in the Users & Groups settings. Log in as Guest and set up the localization the same way it is in your account. Test.

Comment: @LincD. I did that and set the settings (which were already set) and it worked. but it still doesn't work in the main account.

Comment: Please move the following subfolders of your home folder to the Desktop, then log out, log back in, and test. If there is no change, you can put them back where they were. Otherwise, delete them.
~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.spotlight
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Spotlight

Comment: @LincD. No, it did not work. It worked, but after 20 seconds it crashed

Comment: Please repeat the last procedure with this folder: ~/Library/IntelligencePlatform

Comment: @LincD. I didn't know what you meant by repeating the last procedure with this folder so I deleted the folder and the same result.

Comment: I would try starting up in safe mode next. Test and then restart as usual. This will rule out most kinds of third-party system modifications, but will also rebuild some caches that can cause weird problems like this one. https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac

Comment: @LincD. I deleted the caches and intelligence platform. Then, I booted into safe mode and tested. It didn't work so I booted into normal mode. It **STILL** doesn't work

Comment: Are any fonts installed in your home folder, in ~/Library/Fonts? If so, please run the built-in Font Book application and check for conflicts or corruption. Then, open the Siri & Spotlight panel in System Settings and uncheck all the options for search results. If Spotlight stops crashing, restore the options a few at a time until you isolate the culprit(s). If Spotlight still crashes even with all the options deselected, there is not going to be an easy solution. You're going to have to start tearing down your home folder. I've never heard of a case like this.

Comment: I found a report from several years ago of Spotlight crashes caused by indexing Bookmarks & History, so you could start by disabling that.

Comment: @LincD. **I TURNED OFF EVERY SINGLE ONE AND IT STILL CRASHES?**

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight problems (regardless of whether they are crashes, incomplete or duplicate results, or high CPU usage) can usually be solved by completely rebuilding the database/index.

Try these commands from a Terminal and see if they help:

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
sudo mdutil -Ea
sudo mdutil -a -i on
```

Also, do you have any 3rd party (non-Apple) plugins in your `/System/Library/Spotlight` folder?

Comment: I checked and there are no third-party plugins.

Comment: Also, I tried these commands and they did nothing.

Answer (score -3):

I am exhausted about this so I switched to Alfred 5

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/343841)

Comment: **I AM THE CREATOR**

Comment: This answer needs revision. Could you elaborate on how this solved your problem?

Comment: I take it that you're not interested in pursuing the matter further. Sorry I couldn't help. Maybe a future macOS update will solve the problem. If so, please update this discussion.

Comment: It's okay. I am getting a new computer in about 2 weeks and not migrating my data.